# Android: Improve to upgrade play-services-safetynet

Tags: android

I'm new in stack overflow, I have warning when update application in google play console like this:
[warning from google play console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8Zba.png)

and then, I found several answer about it is about *exclude safetyNet in build.gradle,* so my question is, if we exclude safetyNet like :

```
configurations.all {
exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-safetynet' }
```

or

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.2.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core'
implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-auth') {
    exclude module: "play-services-safetynet"
}
```

Is there side effect in our firebase, when using application ?
Thank you

Comment: I think we need to wait for the next version of firebase auth library 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth' because it uses internally, excluding a SafetyNet is not the best solution for now. It should be replaced by play integrity API by firebase.